# tokenizer or split string at multiple spaces in java

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I need to tokenize a string where ever there is more than one space.

for instance

```
"HUNTSVILLE, AL                   30   39.8   44.3   52.3"
```

becomes

```
"HUNTSVILLE, AL","30","39.8","44.3","52.3"
```

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "   ");
```

just tokenizes any whitespace, and I can't figure out a regex to do what I need.

Thanks

Comment: @user914763 read your question again, it doesn't make any sense. Provide what you are getting as well as what you WANT to be happening, otherwise no one will be able to help you. As it stands you never actual describe what you want so what you need to do is a mystery to all of us.

Comment: My question makes perfect sense. I have a sample of the text to be parsed and the desired outcome. I got 4 answers that all would have solved my problem from people who are kind enough to be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = "HUNTSVILLE, AL                   30   39.8   44.3   52.3";
String[] parts = s.split("\\s{3,}");
for(String p : parts) {
  System.out.println(p);
}
```

The `\s` matches any white space char, and `{3,}` will match it 3 or more times.

The snippet above would print:

```
HUNTSVILLE, AL
30
39.8
44.3
52.3
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. Much better than tokenizer. I'm going to read up on my regex as soon as I get the chance.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use split?

```
String[] tokens = string.split("  ");
```

You have to filter empty entries though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
String[] result = "HUNTSVILLE, AL                   30   39.8   44.3   52.3".split("[ ]{2,}");
     for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
         System.out.println(result[x]);
```

**[ ] - Represents space**
**{2,} - Represents more than 2**

Answer (score 2):

```
 /*
 * Uses split to break up a string of input separated by
 * whitespace.
 */
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Splitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create a pattern to match breaks
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[ ]{2,}");
        // Split input with the pattern
        String[] result = 
                 p.split("one,two, three   four ,  five");
        for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++)
            System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```